# I need to force my random forest model to learn one crucial relationship between features. How can I achieve that?

Tags: r, random-forest

Say, given 10 independent features as input to my RF model, when feature 1 and feature 3 are 100 (or less), my model output must be 5 despite the values of the other features. How can I teach that relationship to my RF model - so it will always obey that?

I have tried adding repeated artificial data points to the training set where features 1 and 3 are less or equal to 100 and the output is always zero, but the RF model does not seem to understand/learn that relation just based on that.

I also tried to play with (1) number of trees (2) number of nodes and (3) max nodes without any success.

I am using the mlr library in R to create my RF model. Thanks.

Comment: If the output is always 5 for such scenario, can you subset the data into two sets: the feature1 ==  feature3 = 100 set, and the other. For the first set you simply output 5 as the prediction, then you train and build the other set normally?

Comment: This sounds like something that should be a new feature in your dataset. Why not create a new column that reflects the relationship and train the model on that?

Answer (score 1):

Machine learning algorithms are not to know, they predict. A tree-based ML algorithm will give you probabilities of being in each class, not whether it belongs to a particular class. By preparing your labels carefully; if your data has enough examples of which “feature 1 and 3 are less and equal to 100” and the result is 0, it is highly probable that your algorithm will predict its class with a strong accuracy. Obviously,  the strength of the result depends on what your ML task is, what is your data, how it is structured and what your hyperparameter settings are. I do not know if there is another way to **bend** the forest in such a manner.

I know that is not the kind of an answer you expected, but I’ll be glad if I could help.

Answer (score 0):

One way to guarantee this relationship is to specify it explicitly through an if/else statement. E.g.: feature 1 == feature 3 == 100 => output = 5 else output = random forest predictions (you would train the random forest as "normal" is this instance).

A couple of other things:

- changing the number of trees and/or nodes will not change the relationship between features - these are used to control accuracy and over-fitting.
- Introducing artificial data points is risky as it may cause data imbalances within your training set.
- creating a new column in the dataset which reflects the relationship might work, but it is not guaranteed.